# Where should I report issues with the Tor website?

Tags: support, development

I was browsing the Tor website in preparation for the [Project for Awesome](http://www.projectforawesome.com/about) and I noticed some of the links are broken. To whom should I report these issues to? Can I suggest the fix myself?

Answer (score 5):

You should create tickets on [trac](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor).
If you prefer you can use e-mail:

```
Support
help@rt.torproject.org for English    
help-ar@rt.torproject.org for Arabic
help-es@rt.torproject.org for Spanish
help-fa@rt.torproject.org for Farsi
help-fr@rt.torproject.org for French
help-zh@rt.torproject.org for Mandarin
```

...but on e-mail we will create a ticket on Trac, so...